# Deeper documentation for Fancybox2?

Tags: fancybox-2

One solution to adding a swipe function to Fancybox2 is (according to stackoverflow.com/a/15649856/1055987) to add some lines of code to the end of the _setDimension() function. But I don't see "_setDimension" in any of the Fancybox2 documentation I have, though I did find the function in fancybox.js.

But before I start dropping code into functions I know nothing about, is there any kind of a roadmap or extra documentation on the structure of fancybox.js that might help me get to know this code, and what things like _setDimension() are doing?

Thanks

Comment: you don't have to mess with the original fancybox js file. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649856/1055987) you refer only uses a custom script that you can place in any js file or inline in your html code. Other answers suggest to modify the js file though but I wouldn't recommend that (unless you know what you are doing)

Comment: The script to add swipe references "F" - $(F.outer).on('swipeleft', ... - but fancybox.js defines F as a local variable within the fancybox function - var F = $.fancybox = function () ... - so I'm not seeing how the script can be run from any js file.  What am I missing?   Thanks for your help.

Comment: what you are missing is either analyze properly the http://jsfiddle.net/VacTX/4/ sample or (no offense) some more hours of javascript/jQuery study ;) again: forget messing with original fancybox js file, then write the code in the jsfiddle in a separated js file, e.g. `swipe.js`. Then call that file (after jQuery and fancybox js files) with a regular [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag within your html document. Also don't forget to load jQuery UI, which is part of the solution.

Comment: ...or maybe you are looking a different answer. Personally I like Hansinger's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649856/1055987) better

Comment: Yes, we're talking about different answers.  Hansinger's jsfiddle didn't swipe for me so I didn't look at the code. notsure's answer, below Hansinger's, uses the stephband jquery plugins (http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/) which did swipe for me so I went with it. I just had the question about dropping code into the existing fancybox.js _setDimension function. But this turned out to be trivial and the swipe works beautifully.